# Where should I ask questions about ESP8266?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I tried asking general high level (newb-ish) questions about the ESP8266's firmware, how it works, Arduino IDE, sketches in general at Arduino Stack Exchange but was told it was off-topic. I think the IoT site doesn't seem like the right place either and Arduino Stack Exchange seemed like the most relevant to me.

Which site should I post this question?

> **Does flashing ESP8266/ESP-01 firmware mean uploading a new 'sketch' and why different firmware?**
>
> Hi, I am new to IoT and I am now in love with this. However I'm a
> little confused right now with the jargon. My question is similar to
> [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/43446/when-uploading-a-sketch-to-an-esp8266-isnt-that-the-same-as-flashing-firmware). But I do have some extra questions though.
>
> 1. When using ESP as standalone microcontroller, and if I uploaded a
>    sketch written on the Arduino IDE, does that count as 'Arduino
>    firmware' other people are referring to?
> 2. On the Arduino IDE, uploading sketches onto the ESP8266 seems easy by
>    just installing extra libraries from Board Manager and selecting the
>    right board. Is this step equivalent of doing this but for different
>    firmwares such as AT, NodeMCU and Micropython?
> 3. For the NodeMCU dev boards, is the default firmware on the module
>    NodeMCU firmware? If I were to use the Arduino IDE to upload a sketch,
>    does that mean I have overwritten the NodeMCU firmware with my custom
>    'Arduino firmware' sketch?
> 4. To the extent of my knowledge, when using NodeMCU firmware, I would
>    need to code in LUA language using some sort of LUA IDE and if I
>    flashed/uploaded micropython I would need to code in micropython using
>    exclusively the Thonny IDE. And there is no way to code in micropy or
>    LUA from the Arduino IDE.
> 5. Is the reason for using other firmware is because of how the code is
>    compiled and the language used?

Comment: What kind of questions, software or hardware related?

Comment: mostly software, but a little hardware maybe? mostly because it is related to the ESP8266 NodeMCU development board

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/72674/does-flashing-esp8266-esp-01-firmware-mean-uploading-a-new-sketch-and-why-diff) expressed in the title, it seems it's a valid question for both sites.

The problem is that there are multiple questions involved and some deviating from the main question.

The first 3 questions essentially address the main question in different approaches which I consider to be on-topic.

The fourth question (which isn't really one) addresses that Arduino IDE is not the suitable IDE to code in other language than C++ and the last question complements this. These are deviating from the main question while still related.

If you are not sure whether a question is on-topic or not and it's related to IoT/Arduino, I would advise you to post on one of the child metas and ask.

Comment: some answered my questions.. thanks for this advice